# How to configure Mist wallet connect to my ethereum private-net?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, go-ethereum

I setup an Ethereum private-net that help me deploy, testing smart contract locally. I just want to have a UI can deploy smart contract and visually testing assets transfer.

I think Mist is my first choice. So I want to know how to configure Mist redirect to my private-net. If not, do you have any other recommendation?

Thanks!